# DBT Incremental Model Not Running as Full Refresh Despite Using should_refresh() Macro

Tags: sql, macros, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

context:

I'm working on an incremental model in DBT with the following configuration block:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental',
        unique_key = 'unique',
        full_refresh = should_refresh()  --/// I'm using here a macro that return true or false

    )
}}
```

The should_refresh() macro is supposed to return true or false. Here's the macro logic:

```
{% macro should_refresh() %}
    {% set query %}
    select value from table
    where condition  --/// this query brings a string 'YES' or 'NO'
    {% endset %}

    {% set results = run_query(query) %}

    {% if results and results.columns and results.columns|length > 0 %}
        {% set results_list = results.columns[0].values() %}
        {% set param_val = results_list[0] %}
        {% set should_refresh = param_val == 'YES' %}
        {% do return(should_refresh) %}
    {% else %}
        {% do return(false) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

The issue is that even when the query bring a string 'YES' the model still running as a incremental.

I expect that the model do a full_refresh when macro return true